# How to prevent access to php code?

Tags: php, security

Here is a scenario:

A custom php framework is built.
A user manual of the functions is written for developers
Developers are invited / paid to write additional classes, modules or extensions to the framework

But you don't want them to have access to the actual source code

For instance writing (or potentially many other ways):

```
highlight_file(ROOT_PATH_SHARED.SCRIPT_FOLDER.'search.class.php');
```

Is this possible or will someone working within PHP always be able to pull out the source code?

Answer (score 0):

You need to encrypt/obfuscate your source code.
ioncube and zend guard says that they can do it.
I have not had any experience with them however.
Also, if you are using a framework, ensure that they work after encryption.

Answer (score 0):

PHP is an open-source language.  Somebody who knows what they are doing will always be able to read your code, if they have access to the server's file system.
Your developers will need to be able to run the source code, in order to test and debug their own code.  However, they could do their testing remotely, treating your core app as an API.  That way the developers would not require the kind of source code access that would allow them to view, download, or edit your proprietary source code.
The alternative is to encode or encrypt your source code, and decode it at runtime. The problem is, this would not keep out someone who was determined.  If they have access to the file system, they can retrieve your encryption key.  For better security, restrict access to the files themselves.